# Confusing symbolic integration problem

Tags: calculus

Consider the area under one arch of the curve $y(t) = k\sin(wt)$ for $t ≥ 0$ where $k$ and $w$ are positive constants. Note: Use lower case $k$ and $w$ when needed.

Using the form $$\int_A^B k\sin(wt)dt,$$ Find $A$ and $B$.

My attempt to find $A$ is as follows. (I know I did it wrong but I don't know my mistake) 
$$k\left [ -\frac{1}{w} \cos(wt)\right ] $$ 
from $A$ to $B$

$$\left (k\left [ -\frac{1}{w} \cos(wB)\right ]   \right )-\left (k\left [ -\frac{1}{w} \cos(wA)\right ]   \right )$$
and with simplification I got $\cos(wA)=\cos(wB)$.

at this point I used inverse cosine and concluded that 
$$A=\frac{\cos^{-1}(\cos(wB))}{w}$$
which is wrong.
I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Graphically, "one arch" is the interval where $\sin(wt)$ is positive between two of its roots. So you should use $[A,B]=[0,\pi/w]$.

Comment: It seems that you write that the area is equal to $0$.